# zsh completion: _arguments with _files, but only list executable files

Tags: zsh, completion, zsh-completion

I would like to write a ZSH completion where one of the arguments must be an *executable* file.

While `:_files` works well enough to list *all* files, there does not appear to be an easy way to list only *executable* files.  The glob expression `ls *(*)` does this, but I'm not sure how to apply this filter to `:_files`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `_files` can take a glob expression with the `-g` flag.

The resulting autocomplete action then looks like `:_files -g "*(*)"`, where `(*)` is the glob modifier for executable files.